# Make a line break inside a list for a menu

Tags: html, css

What I have:
[image]

What I need:
[image]

The hover effect should be preserved with the transform attribute on CSS, so it gets bigger. When I try setting a max-width for the line break to happen, I get this max-width attempt with LI sizes wrong:
[image]

Anyone got some ideas to preserve the li sizes and still get the line break?

```
index.html < main page html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chulamis</title>
        <meta charset: "UTF-8" 
        name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initual-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="center">
                <iframe src="menu.html" frameborder="0" id="iframe_menu"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
style.css < main page css file
#container{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1500px;
    background: red;
}
#center{
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    height: 1500px;
}
#right{
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1500px;
    background: blue;
}
#iframe_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
menu.html < menu html file
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/menu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu_container">
        <div id="top">
            <ul id="top_menu">
                <li>home</li>
                <li id="empresa">nossa empresa</li>
                <li>lojas</li>
                <li>localização</li>
                <li>contato</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <ul id="bottom_menu">
                <li>produtos</li>
                <li id="loja">loja virtual</li>
                <li>cursos</li>
                <li>serviços</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
menu.css < menu css file
#menu_container{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    height: 1000px;
    width: auto;
}
#top, #bottom{
    background-color: #1b8e99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#top_menu{
    text-align: right;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
#top_menu li:hover{
    background-color:#92c9ce;
    transform:scale(1.2)
}

#banner{
    background-image: url(../img/banner.fw.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a [minimal runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you better. Also show your attempts in code.

Comment: Put `* { outline: 1px dashed }` at the top of your CSS. This way you can see how your elements are positioned and how they are spaced. Chance is that the height of a wrapped `li`  does not fit in your navbar container.

Comment: Put the code blocks so there is enough replication possibility and accepted the edit from a fellow contributor.

Comment: As I suspected in my first comment: in *menu.css* `#top, #bottom { height: 45px }` and `ul li { line-height: 45px }` cause your problem. When a single line wraps into two lines, it gets `90px` tall because of the line height and will not fit in a `45px` tall parent container. BTW, *very* odd approach using an `<iframe>` as menu...

Comment: I see what you are saying, when i remove `line-height:45px` from ul li{} and force a line break with `max-width:12ch;` i get this result https://imgur.com/qB1qjn1. How could i make it so the boxes are the same size and i still get the word wrap?